# dismissViewControllerAnimated differs in ios8 and ios7

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I have a launchViewController A and two other view controllers B and C. In the app, present sequence is A->B->C. I also have a need to dismiss C and directly back to A.

The problem is:
In iOS7, I call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:^{}]` in A. the functions `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` in B view controller will not be called.

But in iOS8, things are different. `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will be called in B view controller. This results in a flashes of B's contents when dismiss.

Can anyone help me to find a way to fix this.

Comment: if you want to dismiss current ViewController in Which you are you should use [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:^{}] instead of [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:^{}]

Answer (score 2):

if you want to dismiss current ViewController in Which you are you should use

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:^{}]

 instead of [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:^{}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using this:

```
- (void)dismissDeepViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion {
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= IOSCapVersion){
        UIView *window = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window;
        UIView *view = [window snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:false];
        [((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window addSubview:view];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:^{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:AnimationDurationDismissViewController animations:^{
                view.alpha = 0;
            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    [view removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }];

            completion();
        }];
    }
    else{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:^{
            completion();
        }];
    }
}
```